# Create charts with different parameter on same dimension in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm creating dual graphs on the same worksheet in Tableau which is Box plot and line chart. My dimension "Organisation" contains 3 values which are A, B and C. Now, I want to produce a box plot with "B" and Line chart with "C" on the same worksheet. The problem I encountered is filtering the dimension value. I am not able to select separate filters for the graphs. 
Is there any way around to tackle this issue? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create two calculation variables as below

```
Column1
if [Organization] = 'A' then <output Column> end

Column2
if [Organization] = 'C' then <output Column> end
```

Design your dashboard using these two calculated columns and add a filter of Organization in A and C
Hope this helps

Comment: After creating the calculation variable, I am still not able to select the organisation on an individual basis. If I select then individually, then it's affecting both the graphs. 
I created the calculated field, but I got confused in "add a filter of Organization in A and C".
Can you please elaborate your explanation, as I think I am not able to understand properly. Thanks  @Pulkit